# MissingSetupFile issue - file does not exist

Tags: 2013, powershell, content-database, delete, health-analyzer

I am trying to get rid of the health error **[MissingSetupFile]**.
I followed some guide to get (querying the contentDB) the *Id* of the file (and of the *Site* and *Web*).

The issue is that **the file does not exist** anymore on SharePoint but it is still referenced in the ContentDB (*AllDocs table*).

To get the file I used:

```
$file=web.GetFile([Guid]"itemid")
```

and to check if exists:

```
$file.Exists #return true!
```

I checked also in the document library (not programmatically) and it does not exist.

Can I simply *delete the record from the table AllDocs in the contentDB*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved **cleaning the recycle bin** for the site collection. (the files are still stored in the contentDB until the recycle been is empty).

```
(Get-SPSite http://mySite).RecycleBin.DeleteAll()
```